# What is the difference between [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] and [NSMutableDictionary new]?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

When creating a new NSDictionary object in Objective-C, you can do either:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
// or 
NSMutableDictionary *dict= [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

I was wondering what is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 2):

There's probably no functional difference. 
`new` is a short form for `[[Class alloc] init]` form and works with all classes.
`dictionary` is specific method for NSDictionary but is used for `NSMutableDictionary` to create an empty dictionary.

In the past, before ARC, `dictionary` would return an autoreleased object and `new` would return a retained one. That's probably the main difference between these two.